# How can I make a position absolute NOT overlap content when resized?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am working out of WordPress. I downloaded a social icons plugin and placed it on my fixed navigation bar. I used position absolute so that it wouldn't take up any space and make the navigation box larger.

I use the theme pagelines DMS

this is the code I used to place my social icons at the top of the page on my navigation bar.

```
.social-icons {
    position: absolute;
    left: 420px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Every time I resize the browser, the icons overlap my menu tabs.

I want it to adjust and not overlap any content when the window gets smaller.

I tried using @media, but it has not worked for me

please visit https://hughesjobs.net to see exactly what I am referring to

Comment: when you reduce the width of the browser the menu goes all the way up to the logo, then falls below the logo - so the social icons have no where to go - where would you ideally want them to go when you resize?

Comment: I want them to disappear after it gets passed 600 px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, Reduce the image size. this will help you to get the better UI look.

```
       @media screen and (max-width: 1279px) {

 a.sficn img{
   padding-bottom: 25px !important;
   margin: -18px !important;
   width: 17px;
   height:auto ;
}
```